# Next.js Sample Site Installation Failed

Tags: helix, jss, nextjs, sample

I am trying to install Next.js Helix Example site:

Everything looks good until items are serialized:

```
Successfully built ec6606563cd4
Successfully tagged basic-company-nextjs-rendering:latest
Starting Sitecore environment...
basic-company-nextjs_mssql_1 is up-to-date
basic-company-nextjs_solr_1 is up-to-date
basic-company-nextjs_id_1 is up-to-date
Starting basic-company-nextjs_solr-init_1 ... done
basic-company-nextjs_xconnect_1 is up-to-date
basic-company-nextjs_cm_1 is up-to-date
basic-company-nextjs_xdbsearchworker_1 is up-to-date
basic-company-nextjs_traefik_1 is up-to-date
Recreating basic-company-nextjs_rendering_1 ... done
Waiting for CM to become available...
Restoring Sitecore CLI...
Tool 'sitecore.cli' (version '3.0.0') was restored. Available commands: sitecore

Restore was successful.
Logging into Sitecore...
>> Begin installing NuGet packages: Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Publishing@3.0.0-r00259.1, Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization@3.0.0-r00259.1
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to install NuGet package 'Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Publishing'. Ensure package names and versions are valid and that NuGet is installed.
 Sources:https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json
https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2)
 ---> Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.InvalidConfigurationException: Unable to install NuGet package 'Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Publishing'. Ensure package names and versions are valid and that NuGet is installed.
 Sources:https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json
https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.NugetApiClient.NugetApiResolver.InstallPackage(String packageId, String version, String nuGetPackageDirectory) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration\NugetApiClient\NugetApiResolver.cs:line 40
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.ExternalPackageResolver.InstallNuGetPackages(IReadOnlyList`1 nuGetPackageSpecs, String nuGetPackageDirectory) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration\ExternalPackageResolver.cs:line 93
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Client.Cli.Plugins.PluginHelper.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<ResolvePluginAssembly>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Client.Cli\Plugins\PluginHelper.cs:line 211
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Client.Cli.Plugins.PluginHelper.ResolvePluginAssembly(IEnumerable`1 pluginNuGetPackages, String rootDirectory) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Client.Cli\Plugins\PluginHelper.cs:line 211
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I can connect to Sitecore backend:

[image]

Any idea what am I missing?